# How to identify a previous span element inside a div in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application i have two div's. First div contains a span inside it. Second div is collection of 5 div element. While clicking any one of 3 div's in the second div i want to know/find the first div that is a id of span inside that div. Please any one help me to solve this.

**EDITED:**
HTML

```
<ul>

  <li>

            <div class="fleft">
              <span id="user_id" class="no-class"> User</span>
            </div>
             <div style="display: inline-block;">                  
                  <div class="info left no-class section">Jan</div>

            </div>
  </li>
 <li>

            <div class="fleft">
              <span id="user_id" class="no-class"> User</span>
            </div>
             <div style="display: inline-block;">                  
                  <div class="info left no-class section">Jan</div>

            </div>
  </li>
<ul>
```

JS

```
$('.info').click(function(event){
});
```

Note:
In my second div i have 3 elements (original code contains a loop to create 3 div's).In that div I m able to get the next and previous div using prev();, next();. But unable to find the span with id of user_id .

**Edited:**
In one li i have two div's. 
Div1

```
<div class="fleft"><span id="user_id_1"></span></div>
```

Div2

```
 <div class="right">
     <div class="info left no-class section> Jan</div>
     <div class="info left no-class section> Feb</div>
     <div class="info left no-class section> March</div>
 </div>
```

While clicking the Jan/Feb/March I want to know the id of span that is inside the DIV1.

UpdtedFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uj8ox3o1/2/

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate, and your description of your problem isn't very clear

Comment: Yes http://jsfiddle.net/uj8ox3o1/ this is the jfiddle link.

Comment: Still don't get it.... you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/uj8ox3o1/2/

Comment: alert($('.fleft').children('span').attr('id')); ? http://jsfiddle.net/uj8ox3o1/5/

Comment: I updated my question which has two li

Answer (score 1):

If I understand properly you want to find the associated value of the user-id span...

HTML:

```
 <ul>
    <li>
        <div class="fleft"> <span id="user_id1" class="no-class"> User</span>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <div class="info left no-class section">Jan</div>
            <div class="info left no-class section">Feb</div>
            <div class="info left no-class section">Mar</div>
            <div class="info left no-class section">Apr</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="fleft"> <span id="user_id2" class="no-class"> User</span>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <div class="info left no-class section">Jan</div>
            <div class="info left no-class section">Feb</div>
            <div class="info left no-class section">Mar</div>
            <div class="info left no-class section">Apr</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('.info').click(function (event) {
   var id = $(this).closest('li').find('.fleft span[id]').attr('id');
   alert(id);
});
```

This will alert the value of the id specified on your `span`, no matter which of the month `div`s you click

[*** Updated fiddle ***](http://jsfiddle.net/uj8ox3o1/8/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But for each user i have Jan, feb, march. So i want to know the particular user span id.

Comment: @Sami I have updated my answer - is this what you want?

Comment: Thank you for Your Answer i just find it as below. Thank you for your response:)

Comment: @Sami No problem :) Please mark as answer if this worked for you

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>

  <li>

            <div class="fleft">
              <span id="user_id" class="no-class"> User</span>
            </div>
             <div style="display: inline-block;">                  
                  <div class="info left no-class section">Jan</div>

            </div>
  </li>
 <li>

            <div class="fleft">
              <span id="user_id" class="no-class"> User</span>
            </div>
             <div style="display: inline-block;">                  
                  <div class="info left no-class section">Jan</div>

            </div>
  </li>
<ul>


 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $("ul li div span").click('on',function(){
       $id=$(this).attr('id');
                    alert($id);
    });
    });
   </script>
```

demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nc9ycfk3/1/).

Answer (score 0):

In JS

```
$('.info').click(function(event){
   parent_element = this.parentNode;
   adjacent_element = $(parent_element).prev();
   adjacent_element.children('span')[0].id;
});
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery anyway you can do it in one single line (as per my earlier answer). Not sure what value this brings

Answer (score -1):

please describe your problem more clear
this is I get :
if your clicked element have ID of your wanted span is get easier

```
$('.info').click(function(event){
$(this).parents('div.fleft').find('span#ID')
});
```

this is what I get from your question :|

Comment: he wants the id of a span in a div 4 levels up

Comment: really?! :| ok...he shoud add this after 'find' : span:eq(3)